# Why is Webpack 5 Having Trouble with Optional Chaining?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I am upgrading a legacy TypeScript project that uses Webpack, and I have upgraded to the latest Webpack (5.89.0) and `babel-loader` (9.1.3). However, when I compile the project, I get this error:

```
priority-queue.js:32 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (43:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|       const abortHandler = () => {
|           operation.stop();
>           reject(options.signal?.reason);
|       };
| 
    at ./node_modules/p-retry/index.js (priority-queue.js:32:1)
```

It looks like the issue is with the optional chaining in the `p-retry` library. Webpack 5 should have no issues with that. For good measure I even tried to help by adding plugnis Webpack 4 needed, but that didn't work:

```
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                            options: {
                                presets: [
                                    ["@babel/preset-env", {"modules": false, "useBuiltIns": "usage", "corejs": 3}],
                                ],
                                plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining", "@babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator"],
                                cacheDirectory: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The latest Webpack version is [`5.89.0`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v5.89.0) – could you clarify what you mean by "upgraded to the latest Webpack (5.1.4)"?

Comment: Good catch. I was looking at `webpack-cli` in my IDE. Webpack itself is at `5.89.0`